# Tycho: 'Unable to satisfy dependency ...' when building via multi-module parent

Tags: maven, tycho

I have to build an Eclipse-plugin with a Maven/Tycho which has dependencies to other 3rd parties. As embedding dependencies is not yet supported by Tycho, I split up projects into two as following:

- `A-thirdparty`: project with a packaging 'bundle', built by **maven-bundle-plugin**, having **'Embed-Dependency'** instruction, and exporting all packages which are required by a plug-in **'A'**
- `A`: project with a packaging 'eclipse-plugin', using tycho-maven-plugin, and Tycho's target-platform-configuration plug-in with `pomDependencies` set to `consider`.

When I build them separately (at first, thirdparty aggregator, then project A itself), everything works fine. However, if I aggregate both those projects (using multi-module POM), I get the following Maven ERROR:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from A 1.0.0.qualifier to package org.apache.axis2.transaction 0.0.0.", "Unable to satisfy dependency from A 1.0.0.qualifier to package org.apache.axis2.addressing.i18n 0.0.0.", ...
```

Why does building projects in aggregated fashion causes this error, and what kind of workaround could be possible if that's a Tycho bug?

Though, there's no error if I leave only one module in aggregation POM (independently which one).

**EDIT**

Cannot reproduce with a small, similar multi-module sample. Which means there's something about my POM hierarchy.

**EDIT2**

**Was able to reproduce** with a small, similar multi-module sample, after including same set of dependencies (couple of axis2 & axiom libs).

**EDIT3: Minimalistic Example**

Now I'm wondering if the problem is about missing all thirdparties **required by** thirdparty libraries I included. If so, then why am I able to build successfully when executing both modules separately, and build fails only when done via parent, multi-module pom.xml? The example below includes only one single axis2-kernel JAR, bundled in a pom-first artifact named **first-thirdparty**.

Instead of `A`, example has keywoard `first`. The folder structure is as following:

```
./pom.xml
./first-thirdparty
    pom.xml
./first
    src/main/java/org/mydemo/Test.java // has just one method that simply returns AxisFault.class.getSimpleName(); to test import resolution
    META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    build.properties
    pom.xml
```

Root pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.mydemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>first-aggregator</artifactId>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <modules>
        <module>first-thirdparty</module>
        <module>first</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

POM of `first-thirdparty`. It simply embeds axis2-kernel JAR (no other libraries..):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi=           "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.mydemo</groupId>
        <artifactId>first-aggregator</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <manifest-location>META-INF</manifest-location>
    </properties>

    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <groupId>org.mydemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>first-thirdparty</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Embed-Dependency>
                            axis2-kernel
                        </Embed-Dependency>
                        <_exportcontents>
                            org.apache.axis2.*;version="1.5.1"
                        </_exportcontents>
                        <Bundle-ClassPath>{maven-dependencies}</Bundle-ClassPath>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                        <Embed-Directory>jars</Embed-Directory>
                        <_failok>true</_failok>
                        <_nouses>true</_nouses>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

POM of `first`, which is an eclipse-plugin, and depends on `first-thirdparty`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.mydemo</groupId>
        <artifactId>first-aggregator</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.mydemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.mydemo.first-bundle</artifactId>

    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <tycho.ver>0.14.1</tycho.ver>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>helios</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mydemo</groupId>
            <artifactId>first-thirdparty</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build> 
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.ver}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.ver}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

MANIFEST.MF of module `first`; it explicitly imports all packages of axis2-kernel:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Tool: Bnd-0.0.357
Bundle-Name: first-bundle
Bnd-LastModified: 1334819004300
Created-By: 1.6.0_25 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.mydemo.first-bundle
Export-Package: org.mydemo
Import-Package: org.apache.axis2.clustering.context,
 org.apache.axis2.modules,
 org.apache.axis2.deployment.util,
 org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.client,
 org.apache.axis2.clustering,
 org.apache.axis2.wsdl.util,
 org.apache.axis2.clustering.configuration,
 org.apache.axis2.java.security,
 org.apache.axis2.deployment.resolver,
 org.apache.axis2.util,
 org.apache.axis2.wsdl,
 org.apache.axis2.addressing.metadata,
 org.apache.axis2.i18n,
 org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler,
 org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval,
 org.apache.axis2.dispatchers,
 org.apache.axis2.transport,org.apache.axis2.service,
 org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util,
 org.apache.axis2.client,
 org.apache.axis2.context,
 org.apache.axis2.classloader,
 org.apache.axis2.receivers,
 org.apache.axis2.engine,
 org.apache.axis2.addressing,
 org.apache.axis2.deployment,
 org.apache.axis2.transport.http,
 org.apache.axis2.phaseresolver,
 org.apache.axis2.context.externalize,
 org.apache.axis2.transaction,
 org.apache.axis2.description,
 org.apache.axis2.addressing.wsdl,
 org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util,
 org.apache.axis2.util.threadpool,
 org.apache.axis2,
 org.apache.axis2.handlers,
 org.apache.axis2.addressing.i18n,
 org.apache.axis2.builder,
 org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl,
 org.apache.axis2.builder.unknowncontent,
 org.apache.axis2.namespace,
 org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.bytecode,
 org.apache.axis2.client.async,
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Bundle-Localization: plugin
```

Comment: It would help to show us your master pom.xml as well as what commands you're invoking Maven with.

Comment: @SpellingD Ok, I'll put the code sample, as I managed to minimize the code.

Comment: @SpellingD There's not that much of code, but I'm considering to move it to some sharing storage. If you can suggest one, please do so. I'm wondering now, if the issue about that Axis2 dependencies are not included, and this affects build process. However, I'm able to build these modules separately, so I'm wondering what's wrong about aggregating them via multi-module parent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not possible to build "POM-first" bundles (i.e. bundles built with maven-bundle-plugin) and "MANIFEST-fist" bundles (i.e. bundles built by Tycho) in the same reactor. This is a [known limitation in Tycho](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393053).

The reason is that Tycho does its dependency resolution too early in the Maven lifecycle when the maven-bundle-plugin has not yet had a chance to generate the Manifest (needed by Tycho). Addressing this problem needs [quite large changes](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353889), but I still hope to get this done in mid-term.

Comment: Thanks, this is a really valuable comment. I'll make sure to open request as soon as possible, as we're interested in getting this case working within a single build. I'm accepting your answer as it clearly explains the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have just get same issue.I solve my issue this way hope this would help you

1  the reason you get the error is because you lack of plugin jars. for example in you case

> "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the
> problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from A
> 1.0.0.qualifier to package org.apache.axis2.transaction 0.0.0.","

Just look at the first one, you do not have `org.apache.axis2.transaction 0.0.0.` in your maven repository.  To be honest, i am not sure what is jar used for and how to get it, I was just missing some plugin dependency from other version of eclipse so i just need jar in /eclipse/plugins
So what you do is create a p2 repository yourself. Here is another guy who right a link how to use script to create the p2 repository http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2010/11/26/creating-a-p2-repository-from-features-and-plugins/

2 put this repository in ur maven pom file

```
    <repository>
        <id>localP2resp</id>
        <url>file:///F:/P2Repository</url>
        <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
```

3 So far you should fix the problem if you have the plugin jars that you need in you P2repository

if you have any other questions or not so satisfy with mine answer, keep asking.